# BB30 to BSA frame conversion with internal cable routing?

Tags: frames, bb30, bsa

I'm interested in using BSA crank parts with a certain BB30 frame and I'm a little unclear about cable routing, I'm hoping somebody here can help clarify the confusion.

I'm considering purchasing a Dengfu FM286:

http://dengfubikes.com/Cyclo_Cross/112.html

The concern is that I'm going to use a BSA crank parts and they only have a BB30 frame available in my size (3 month wait for BSA version in the proper size).

I'm under the impression that frames with internal cable routing can allow the cables to pass the BB area in one of two ways, either through the BB opening, or underneath on the bottom of the frame in tubes, is this correct?

For the typical BB30 to BSA adapters, for example:

http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/us/en/fsa-bb30-threaded-adapter-b3119-/rp-prod129935?gs=1&gclid=CPqZv9_6oNICFc-1wAodPNUJfw&gclsrc=aw.ds

http://www.competitivecyclist.com/sram-bb30-to-bsa-bottom-bracket-adaptor-kit

I'm under the impression that these could be used on a frame where the cables route in tubes underneath the frame, but could not be used in a frame where cables route through the BB opening, correct?

If so, here is the further confusion on my part.  I emailed Dengfu pertaining to the frame linked above, and received this response:

*"I show you pictures of BSA adapter and BB30 frame bottom. You can install cables internally."*

Here are the pics they sent:

[image]

[image]

So I'm left with some questions:

-For the adapter (1st pic), is this a BB30 to BSA adapter with pre-machined holes?  It appears to be but I'm not sure

-For the frame (2nd pic), does that appear to be a BB30 frame?  I would suspect so since there don't appear to be BB threads but I'm not sure.

-Also for the frame, are those two tubes on the bottom of the frame (they appear to be gold colored in the pic, but that's probably just the lighting, I would suspect they are actually white) where the cables route through?  If so, does that mean any BB30 to BSA adapter could be pressed in and still allow the cable routing, or is it still necessary to utilize the BB hole in some way?

I will contact the company further about this, but I'm also interested in the expertise of anybody in this forum that can offer information about BB30 to BSA conversion for an internally routed cable frame, and also your impressions of the images above.  Please advise, thanks!

Comment: BB30 shells with the cables routed through such that you have to remove the cranks etc to access them have become pretty uncommon on new bikes because everyone hates them. Also you could just use the step down rather than press style adapters even if you did have that kind, presuming you're using some kind of outboard bearing crank.

Answer (score 1):

In the first picture it looks like the holes are simply machined to decrease the weight of the adapter without compromising strength. My only concern with the frame and adapter would be tolerances because you wouldn't want it to fit too loose.

The second picture definitely looks like a bb30 frame but without calipers it's impossible to know the diameter and width for sure.

The gold/red tubes you see on the bottom are the internally routed guides for the rear derailleur cable and rear brake cable/hose. Since this frame has a lower compartment where the cables route, you will not have any issues with internal cable routing with any bottom bracket combination.